# Does Android ship with fftw

Tags: android, fftw, dynamic-library

I'm working on a cross-mobile project that requires performant real-time FFT.

iOS is easy thanks to the vDSP FFT.

Android I cannot see a clear path. Best option I can see: dynamic-link to FFTW. But do I need to supply an FFTW dylib with the project? Or can I reasonably expect an android device to have that library?

Comment: Unless what you want appears [in the NDK documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis.html), you should plan on baking the library into your app.

Comment: @CommonsWare Don't think GPL license allows that... :/

Comment: You would have to ship your app licensed under the GPL. Or, see if the library developers will sell you a commercial license. Or, use a different library. Or, write your own library.

Comment: Not sure why this is being down-voted - it’s a tricky problem which is often encountered when working with GPL libraries and proprietary deliverables.